# Why does my subclassed button procedure mess up my program?

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

I am relatively new to C++. I have a question why the program posted below behaves the way it does when the constant DEMOMETHOD is set to 1 in main.cpp and button_class.h.

The program demonstrates subclassing a few buttons created  by a single c++ class - there are 4 instances of the class (4 buttons) and two (labeled button1 and button2) are subclassed.

I'm hoping to learn:

1. why return 0; is needed in the handler of the wm_lbuttondown message in button_class.cpp for multiinstance subclassing to work correctly (set DEMOMETHOD = 0 for correct program operation).
2. why the other subclassed buttons and the non subclassed buttons work incorrectly after either one of the two subclassed buttons are clicked.  Example: the quit button doesn't work if you first click on Button 2 (or 1) when DEMOMETHOD = 1.

I posted compilable (gcc compiler, Windows 7) code to make it easier to observe the behavior I saw and to, hopefully, help other new c++ programmers that stumble upon this post.

Thanks in advance.

```
//best way to use a defined constant in two cpp files is to use a header (.h) file that is shared by the two cpp files.
//I want to minimize how many files I post, so I define DEMOMETHOD in two separate files
//also set to 1 or 0 in button_class.h
#define DEMOMETHOD  1 //SET TO 1 to make program break, set to 0 to make program work (do this in the button_class.h file too)

#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h> //for _T
//windows 7 flags
#define WINVER          0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 // Windows 7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700  //windows 7
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN //results in smaller exe
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "button_class.h"//my button class

using namespace std;

//forward declares
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
std::string str(long data);

//declares-pre
#define IDC_CHECKBOX101     101
#define IDC_BUTTON1         102
#define IDC_BUTTON2         103
#define IDC_STATIC          104

//globals, create 4 buttons using our button class, 2 will be subclassed
Button bt,cbt,bt1,bt2;//button and checkbox button
HWND hDlg,hstatic; //main window and static label
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("MyWindowsApp");
HINSTANCE hInstance;

//main window, starts the program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument,int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG messages;
    std::string tmp;

    hInstance = hInst;//save instance to global variable

    //create and register our main window class
    WNDCLASSEX wincl; // Data structure for the windowclass
    wincl.hInstance = hInst;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; // This function is called by windows
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;  // Catch double-clicks
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    // Use default icon and mouse-pointer
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL; // No menu
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;  // No extra bytes after the window class
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;  // structure or the window instance
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_3DFACE+1);

    // Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed to register WNDCLASSEX.","Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 1;//exit program on failure
    }

//class is registered, now create main window

      hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
               0,//extended style
               szClassName,
               _T("Demo Multi Instance of Button Class"),
               WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // styles - default window
               CW_USEDEFAULT,       // Windows decides the position
               CW_USEDEFAULT,       // where the window ends up on the screen
               777,                 // The program's width (hardcoded for this demo)
               411,                 // and height in pixels (hardcoded for this demo)
               HWND_DESKTOP,        // The window is a child-window to desktop
               NULL,                // No menu
               hInst,               // Program Instance handler
               NULL                 // No Window Creation data
           );

    if (!hwnd) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed to create main window.","Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return 1;//exit program on failure
    }
    hDlg = hwnd;//main window

    // Make the window visible on the screen
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow (hwnd);

    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        // Translate virtual-key messages into character messages
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        // Send message to WindowProcedure (WndProc)
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    // The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave
    return messages.wParam;
}


//handle messages intended for main window
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::string tmp;
    LRESULT checked;
    DWORD dwstyles,dwstylesex;

    switch (message) { //wndproc handle the messages

    case WM_CREATE://create controls
//always on top checkbox button (not subclassed)
        dwstyles = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX;
        dwstylesex = 0;
        cbt.t.hbutton = cbt.Create(hwnd,cbt,dwstylesex,dwstyles,277,8,122,26,(long) IDC_CHECKBOX101,hInstance,"Always on top",false);

//quit button (not subclassed)
        dwstyles =   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP;
        dwstylesex = 0;
        bt.t.hbutton = bt.Create(hwnd,bt,dwstylesex,dwstyles,691,7,65,30,(long) IDCANCEL,hInstance,"&Quit",false);

//button1 (subclassed)
        dwstyles =   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP;
        dwstylesex = 0;
        bt1.t.hbutton = bt1.Create(hwnd,bt1,dwstylesex,dwstyles,50,50,65,30,(long) IDC_BUTTON1,hInstance,"Button1",true);
        if (bt1.t.hbutton == NULL) {
            MessageBox(NULL,"button1 failed","error",0);
        }

//button2 (subclassed)
        dwstyles =   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP;
        dwstylesex = 0;
        bt2.t.hbutton = bt2.Create(hwnd,bt2,dwstylesex,dwstyles,50,90,65,30,(long) IDC_BUTTON2,hInstance,"Button2",true);
        if (bt2.t.hbutton == NULL) {
            MessageBox(NULL,"button2 failed","error",0);
        }

//create a statio control and display information about DEMOMETHOD
        hstatic = CreateWindowEx(0,"Static",
#if (DEMOMETHOD == 0)
                                 "Program should work correctly since DEMOMETHOD is set to 0",
#else
                                 "Program should mess up since DEMOMETHOD is set to 1",
#endif
                                 WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                 50, 140,
                                 450, 30,
                                 hwnd,
                                 (HMENU) IDC_STATIC,
                                 hInstance,
                                 NULL);



        break;

    case WM_SIZE:
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);   // send a WM_QUIT to the message queue
        break;
    }

    case WM_CLOSE: {
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {// LOWORD ctrlid. The HIWORD specifies the notification code.

        case IDC_CHECKBOX101: { // always on top
            //leftover functionality from another app
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {
                checked = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
                if (checked) { // Force the program to stay always on top
                    SetWindowPos(hDlg, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
                } else { // else no more topmost program state
                    SetWindowPos(hDlg, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
                }
            }
            break;
        }


        case IDCANCEL: {//quit button
            if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {
                PostMessage(hDlg,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }//idcancel
        }// loword switch
        break;
    }//wm_command

    default:  // for messages that we don't deal with
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    } //for switch(msg)

    return 0;
}//end wndproc function

std::string str(long data)//convert non decimnal numeric to string
{
    try {
        return std::to_string((long) data);
    } catch(int x) {
        return std::to_string((long) data);
    }
    return "error in str function";
}
```

```
button_class.h

#ifndef BUTTONCLASSGUARD
#define BUTTONCLASSGUARD

//best way to use a defined constant in two cpp files is to use a header (.h) file that is shared by the two cpp files.
//I want to minimize how many files I post, so I define DEMOMETHOD in two separate files
//also set to 1/0 in main.cpp
#define DEMOMETHOD  1 //SET TO 1 to make program break (do this in main.cpp file too) set to 0 to make program work

#include <iostream>
//windows 7 flags
#define WINVER  0x0601 //windows 7
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 // Windows 7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2019
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700  //windows 7
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN //results in smaller exe
#include <windows.h>
//#include <windowsx.h> //for get_x_lparam
#include <commctrl.h> //for subclass safer also make sure linker calls libcomctl32.a (gcc compiler)

class Button //define the Button class
{
private:

public:

    struct T { //seems like a more convenient way to allow sets/gets for a class that only I will use
        long x;
        long xx;
        long y;
        long yy;
        HWND hparent;
        HINSTANCE hinstance;
        long ctrlid;
        HWND hbutton;
    } t;

    Button() //constructor
    {
    }

    ~Button() //destructor
    {
    }

//forward declares
    HWND Create(HWND hparent, Button &tbt,DWORD dwstylesex,DWORD dwstyles, int x,int y, int xx, int yy, long ctrlid, HINSTANCE hinst, std::string Caption, bool SubClassTF);

//next is our callback function for safe subclassing using setwindowsubclass
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview
//stackoverflow article said static is needed and my testing confirmed this
    static LRESULT CALLBACK OnEvent_Button(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
};//Button class end
#endif//buttonclassguard
```

```
button_class.cpp
//custom button class
#include "button_class.h"


extern std::string str(long data);//for demo I use extern keyword to give access to str function, normally that function is in a utilities class

HWND Button::Create(HWND hparent, Button &tbt, DWORD dwstylesex, DWORD dwstyles, int x,int y, int xx, int yy, long ctrlid, HINSTANCE hinst, std::string Caption, bool SubClassTF)
{

    HWND result;

    HGDIOBJ hFont = GetStockObject(ANSI_VAR_FONT);
    bool tbool;
    static long InstCount = 0;
    std::string tmp;

    tbt.t.hinstance = hinst;
    tbt.t.x = x;
    tbt.t.xx = xx;
    tbt.t.y = y;
    tbt.t.yy = yy;
    tbt.t.hparent = hparent;
    tbt.t.ctrlid = ctrlid;
//now create a button

    tbt.t.hbutton = (HWND) NULL;

    if (dwstyles == 0) {
        dwstyles =  WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | BS_NOTIFY;
    }

    if (Caption == "") {
        Caption = "&Ok";
    }

    result = CreateWindowEx(dwstylesex,"Button",
                            Caption.c_str(),
                            dwstyles,
                            tbt.t.x,tbt.t.y,
                            tbt.t.xx,tbt.t.yy,
                            hparent,
                            (HMENU) ctrlid,
                            hinst,
                            NULL);
    if (!result) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Button creation Failed.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return result;
    }

    if (hFont > 0) {
        SendMessage(result, WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM) hFont, 0);
    }

    if (SubClassTF == true) {
//subclass if here
        InstCount++;//instantiation count
//now subclass using safer method https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110506-00/?p=10723 (raymond chen) (safer subclass)

//the 'this' keyword seems to change its stripes depending on whether onevent_button is static or not
// if static it seems to track the instance of the class &tbt)
// if not static (remove static keyword from .h forward declare) it seems to point to the class not an instance of the class
//static is correct for this exercise
        tbool = SetWindowSubclass(
                    result,//window being subclassed
                    reinterpret_cast<SUBCLASSPROC>(this->OnEvent_Button), //&tbt.OnEvent_Button), //&OnEvent_Button), //or &tbt.onevent_button worked too sort of onevent_button can be outside the class
                    InstCount, //id of this subclass, my choice
                    reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(this) //&tbt)//was: (&tbt) ken suspects use of this is ng since, for mult instances this points to the class not the instance of the class imho semi tested
                );//returns bool with result

        if (tbool == false) { //subclass failed if false
            tmp = "subclass failed for " + Caption;
            MessageBox(NULL,tmp.c_str(),"error",0);
        }
    } //subclass

    tbt.t.hbutton = result;

    return result;//return hwnd to caller
}//::create funtion end


LRESULT CALLBACK Button::OnEvent_Button(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
//Button *tp = (Button *) dwRefData;//I believe this is the C way, seems to work
    Button *tp = reinterpret_cast<Button *>(dwRefData);//c++ way, works
    std::string tmp;

    switch(uMsg) {

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // onevent_button message
        tmp = "I got clicked: uidsubclass: " + str(uIdSubclass) + " tp->t.y: " + str(tp->t.y) + " dwrefdata: " + str((long) dwRefData) + " hwnd: " + str((long)hwnd) + " click ypos: " + str((long)HIWORD(lParam));
        MessageBox(NULL,tmp.c_str(),"clicked",0);
//question: why is return 0; needed (why do I need to eat the message?)
//if I break; instead, I call defwindowproc and that messes up how the class works if another subclassed button is clicked 2nd
//the nonsubclassed buttons also mess up if DEMOMETHOD is set to 1 and a subclassed button (1 or 2) is clicked before
//a nonsubclassed button. why is that?
#if (DEMOMETHOD == 0)//set demomethod to 1 to break the program
//if here the program/class should work well
        MessageBox(NULL,"return 0 next - should work when you click on another button next","message",0);
        return 0;//needed else 2nd call by a different subclassed control doesn't work
#else
        MessageBox(NULL,"break is next - doesn't work if you click on another button next","message",0);
#endif
        break;//calls defwindowproc -> messes up the ability of the class to distinguish between a button1 or button2 click

    case WM_DESTROY: {//onevent_button message
//remove the subclass
//raymond says: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd,
                             reinterpret_cast<SUBCLASSPROC>(&tp->OnEvent_Button), //thisfunctionname
                             reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(uIdSubclass) //uidsubclass
                            );
        break; //or return DefSubclassProc(hwnd,wMsg,lParam,wParam); //per raymond chen
    } //wm_destroy

    default:

//for regular subclassing:  return CallWindowProc(OldButtonWndProc, hwnd, wm, wParam, lParam);

//for safer subclassing do this per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview
        break;//return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

//I'm a c++ beginner. I notice that most samples by experienced c++ programmers just return 0 next, however
//I find that I was using break in the switch(umsg) section and a call to defsubclassproc was needed so I am doing it this way
//note: for regular subclassing we return CallWindowProc(OldButtonWndProc...

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);//need this if you plan to use break for any case item
} //onevent_button
```

Comment: If you are new to C++, then doing Win32 api code in 2020 might not be the best choice of technology as it is very low level and does not help much in creating modern applications.

Comment: Probably good advice.  I do have significant experience writing programs for business using mostly higher level languages (Basic based) and some low level language experience (Powerbasic sdk version) that uses the win32 api.   There is a lot to learn with C++; I am enjoying the journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, these two problems are caused by the same problem. When you use `return 0`, you will return directly without calling the `DefSubclassProc` function outside of `switch`.

If you use `break`, you will jump out `switch`, call the `DefSubclassProc` function again. This is why the same button is triggered continuously when the `DEMOMETHOD` value is 1.

So the solution is very simple, you just need to modify the following code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Button::OnEvent_Button(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    //Button *tp = (Button *) dwRefData;//I believe this is the C way, seems to work
    Button* tp = reinterpret_cast<Button*>(dwRefData);//c++ way, works
    std::string tmp;

    switch (uMsg) {

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: // onevent_button message
        tmp = "I got clicked: uidsubclass: " + str(uIdSubclass) + " tp->t.y: " + str(tp->t.y) + " dwrefdata: " + str((long)dwRefData) + " hwnd: " + str((long)hwnd) + " click ypos: " + str((long)HIWORD(lParam));
        MessageBox(NULL, tmp.c_str(), "clicked", 0);
        //question: why is return 0; needed (why do I need to eat the message?)
        //if I break; instead, I call defwindowproc and that messes up how the class works if another subclassed button is clicked 2nd
        //the nonsubclassed buttons also mess up if DEMOMETHOD is set to 1 and a subclassed button (1 or 2) is clicked before
        //a nonsubclassed button. why is that?
#if (DEMOMETHOD == 0)//set demomethod to 1 to break the program
//if here the program/class should work well
        MessageBox(NULL, "return 0 next - should work when you click on another button next", "message", 0);
        return 0;//needed else 2nd call by a different subclassed control doesn't work
#else
        MessageBox(NULL, "break is next - doesn't work if you click on another button next", "message", 0);
#endif
        break;//calls defwindowproc -> messes up the ability of the class to distinguish between a button1 or button2 click

    case WM_DESTROY: {//onevent_button message
//remove the subclass
//raymond says: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hwnd,
            reinterpret_cast<SUBCLASSPROC>(&tp->OnEvent_Button), //thisfunctionname
            uIdSubclass //uidsubclass
        );
        break; //or return DefSubclassProc(hwnd,wMsg,lParam,wParam); //per raymond chen
    } //wm_destroy

    default:
        return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        //for regular subclassing:  return CallWindowProc(OldButtonWndProc, hwnd, wm, wParam, lParam);
        //for safer subclassing do this per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview
    }

    //I'm a c++ beginner. I notice that most samples by experienced c++ programmers just return 0 next, however
    //I find that I was using break in the switch(umsg) section and a call to defsubclassproc was needed so I am doing it this way
    //note: for regular subclassing we return CallWindowProc(OldButtonWndProc...

    return 0; //need this if you plan to use break for any case item
} //onevent_button
```

Comment: Thank you.  After reading your answer I took out the MessageBox statements when a wm_lbuttondown message was received and logged the same information I was displaying in the MessageBox. Drum roll please: the program worked as expected regardless of how the DEMOMETHOD flag was set.  Very interesting lesson for me and hopefully for others who stumble upon this post.  Thanks again.